# Navigation Menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in android but i want to make navigation menu in my application. I successfully fetch data from web service. But i have problem in navigation menu how to add web service menu item in navigation menu?
 In this activity First fetch data through web service and then convert json object to array object and then call printmenu function to add menu items in navigation i have problem in this section i dont know how to add menu.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    {
         private ArrayList<MenuItems> menuModel=new ArrayList<>();
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
           {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           }
           public class MenuList extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
           {
             Boolean result = true;
             URL url;
             HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
             String[] response;
             ProgressDialog dialog;
             @Override
             protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
             }

             @Override
             protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
             {
                try{
                    response = new String[params.length];
                    for(int i=0;i<params.length;i++)
                    {
                        url = new URL(params[i]);
                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)       url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        urlConnection.connect();
                        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                        if(responseCode== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                        {
                            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                            response[i] = convertStreamToString(in);
                            Log.d("Passs", response[i]+"");
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
                    result = false;
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    if(result)
                    {
                        allMenuItems(response[0]);
                        //printCategory(response[0]);

                    }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Somthing bad happen ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        private void allMenuItems(String response)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("menu");
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject objMenu=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    MenuItems objectmenu=new MenuItems();
                    objectmenu.setMenu_id(objMenu.getString("category_id"));
                    objectmenu.setMenuitem_item(objMenu.getString("category_name"));
                    objectmenu.setMenu_image(objMenu.getString("category_banner"));
                    menuModel.add(objectmenu);
                }
                printMenu();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
        private void printMenu()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=menuModel.size();i++)
            {



            }
        }
    }
XML File

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="Category"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/gry"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_view"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/image_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src = "@drawable/love"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="19dp"
                        android:text="Ring"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_view"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>


                </RelativeLayout>



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView52"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src = "@drawable/bracelt"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="19dp"
                        android:text="Bracelet"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView52"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView52"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView57"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src = "@drawable/ratenew"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="35dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:text="Rate Us"
                android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView57"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView57"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/></RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView58"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src = "@drawable/gestures"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Today's Deal"
                android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView58"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView58"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"

              />
    </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView59"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src = "@drawable/contect"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:text="Contact Us"
                android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView59"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView59"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
               />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView60"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src = "@drawable/about"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:text="About Us"
                android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView60"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView60"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

                    android:background="@color/lightgray"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="90dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/fb" />

                <ImageView
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src = "@drawable/inst"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src = "@drawable/tw"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"/>

            </RelativeLayout>





        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What error you are getting? post your log too.

Comment: There is no error problem is this i have no idea about how to put menu items dynamicall and how to redirect from one activity to another activity according to menu item id

Answer (score 1):

In the `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask`, call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. That should call the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method again. In `onCreateOptionsMenu`, add the `MenuItem`s from your `menuModel`.